# Lauch my application Intent from android contact details

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to lauch my application Intent from android contact details, like Whatsapp does.
I mean that when you go to native contacts application and open a contact's details you should see, among the details shown, an action to be performed by my own application.
This is possible beacause Whatsapp does it.

Can you help me?

Please.

Comment: Please check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html in emphasis on sync adapters (afaik).
Unfortunately i am not experienced enough in these to provide my own explanation - but at least point you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can help you, but you probably won't like the answer.

Technically, you *can* respond to a click in the native contacts application, by having an intent filter that catches the outgoing intent from "contacts". The problem is that the Contacts app doesn't publish the names of the outgoing Intents. You have to look for them yourself in the Android Open Source Project.

Also, you can't add anything that the Contacts app doesn't already do. The Contacts app doesn't support that.

You can write your own version of the Contacts app and provide the ability to attach any action you want.

Comment: I don't want to filter intents, I want to do it the right way, via adapters!